# How can I count the number of children?

Tags: jquery

I have a list

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
  <li>
  ...
</ul>
```

I need jQuery to count the number of items in my list.

Comment: forget jquery `document.querySelectorAll('ul li').length`

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
var count = $("ul li").length;
```

[`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) tells how many matches the selector found, so this counts how many `<li>` under `<ul>` elements you have...if there are sub-children, use `"ul > li"` instead to get only *direct* children.  If you have other `<ul>` elements in your page, just change the selector to match only his one, for example if it has an ID you'd use `"#myListID > li"`.

In other situations where you don't know the child type, you can use the `*` (wildcard) selector, or `.children()`, like this:

```
var count = $(".parentSelector > *").length;
```

or:

```
var count = $(".parentSelector").children().length;
```

Comment: What if, its not known that the child is "li", and could be anything?

Comment: @Starx: `$("#parent").children().length`

Comment: @AlecAnanian, No, I know how. I mean I was hoping Nick would add that to his answer too.

Comment: @Starx - added in case it helps a few people down the road :)

Comment: What if the element is not visible?

Comment: @MatthewBaker visibility won't matter here, as long as it's present in the DOM.  If it's not there in the DOM...then there's no element/child to count.  If you want explicitly to count visible check out the [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: $("ul li") counts all the li recursively. What if I want to choose only the direct li's ? thanks

Comment: @MihaiZamfir you'd use `$("ui > li")` to get only direct children.

Comment: sorry, I am a beginner. Doesn't this take the first `li` child only?

Comment: @MihaiZamfir nope, that's a selector for all the children - same as it works in CSS

Answer (score 8):

You don't need jQuery for this. You can use JavaScript's `.childNodes.length`.

Just make sure to subtract 1 if you don't want to include the default text node (which is empty by default). Thus, you'd use the following:

```
var count = elem.childNodes.length - 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to get using:

```
var count = $("ul > li").size();
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Element.childElementCount`

> ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/childElementCount

```js
let count = ThatParentElement.childElementCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you are using this to determine the current selector to find its children 
so this holds: `<ol>` then there is `<li>`s under how to write a selector 
`var count = $(this+"> li").length;` wont work..

Comment: if the ol has a class you can write `$("ol.class > li").length`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery:

This method gets a list of its children then counts the length of that list, as simple as that.

```
$("ul").find("*").length;
```

> The find() method traverses DOM downwards along descendants, all the way down to the last descendant.

**Note:** children() method traverses a single level down the DOM tree.