# Is it possible to test how many options are in a select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery 1.6.2.

I am dynamically populating a select box using ColdFusion and jQuery.

When the options are returned and stuffed inside the select box, I'd jQuery to figure out how many options there are and adjust the size attr as needed.

```
// load the options into the select box
$("#Select").load("GlobalAdmin/ArtistUnassociatedAlbums.cfm?" + QString);

// test the number of options
var NumOfOptions = $();
var BoxSize = 0;

// do a calculation
if (NumOfOptions > 10) {
    BoxSize = 10;
} else {
    BoxSize = NumOfOptions ;
}

// adjust the select box size
$("#AlbumsSelect").attr("size", BoxSize );
```

How do I efficiently get at the number of options returned?

Comment: Can you stop writing tags in all your titles, please?

Comment: What is "the latest and greatest jQuery"? This statement is dependent upon a point in time, but this question post will last for [potentially] _years_. Tell us precisely which version you're using; it won't hurt!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: how can I count the number of children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/jquery-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children)

Comment: @Felix, my question is more explicit. The other question is more conceptual. Also, that guy put "jQuery" in his question and should be admonished, just as I was. :>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea just use the `length` property...

```
var numOfOptions = $('#Select option').length;
```

Comment: @Evik James, no problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: I will happily do so as soon as I am able to. I tried, but I think there's a ten minute minimum.

Answer (score 3):

Just select the options and test the length property of the resulting jQuery object:

```
console.log($("#Select option").length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use javascript's property .length

```
var length = $("option").length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var NumOfOptions = $("#AlbumsSelect option").length;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is perfect too.  Thanks!