# Count number of divs inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="full">
        <?php $i=0; $j=1; foreach ($array as $image){ ?>
        <div id="image<?php echo $i;?>" class="img bg-img<?php echo $j;?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['image']; ?>" ></img></div>
        <?php $j++; $i++;} ?>           

    </div>
```

How do i get the number of divs contained by div id="full"?.

Comment: I'd clarify whether you want only children divs (rich.okelly's solution), or ALL divs aka descendants (Shomz's solution)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I count the number of children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children)

Comment: @JohnStrickler + for the comment; according to his code, there are only children divs, though

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
$('#full > div').length
```

[See here for jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KP3uw/)

Comment: Just for a small note: the assicoated JQuery method is '.size()'. I know that Jquery stores it's results in an ordinary array.

Comment: @reporter to be perfectly accurate, jQuery masks itself as an Array-like object, not a real array.

Comment: @reporter: Nevertheless it is recommended to use `length` instead of `size`: *"The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call."*

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`$('div#full div').length;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('#full > div').length
```

docs on : http://api.jquery.com/size/

Answer (score 1):

`var divCount = $('#full').children('div').length;`

Answer (score 0):

you can get like this:

```
<div id="full">
<?php $total = count($array); ?>
<?php $i=0; $j=1; foreach ($array as $image){ ?>
        <?php $i=0; $j=1; foreach ($array as $image){ ?>
        <div id="image<?php echo $i;?>" class="img bg-img<?php echo $j;?>"><img src="<?php echo $image['image']; ?>" ></img></div>
        <?php $j++; $i++;} ?>           

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count= $("#full > div").size()
```

Now variable count will have the number of divs

I just realized that size() returns same as length. But using length, you avoid an extra method call. So go for length.