# How to check if number of elements within parent is even

Tags: jquery

I have HTML in this structure:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>name</li>
    <li>name</li>
    <li>name</li>
    <li>name</li>
</ul>
```

I want check if the count of `li` elements is even. How can I use this in an `if` statement?

Comment: Have a look at [How can I count the number of children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children) and [Testing whether a value is odd or even](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211613/testing-whether-a-value-is-odd-or-even).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($('ul.list > li').length %2 != 0){
    // Odd
}else{
    // Even
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('ul>li').length % 2 == 0)
{
   // do if even
}
else
{
   // do if not
}
```

Also, if you need to apply to the even items something you can use:

```
$('ul>li:even').addClass('even')
```

Or odd:

```
$('ul>li:odd').addClass('even')
```