# style dropdownlist from typeahead in modal with jquery css( )

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. I'm trying to jquery-css a dropdownlist from typeahead. The typeahead is in a modal.
This code should work but it doesn't

```
$(function(){
    $("ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu li:even").css({ 
        'background': 'white'
});
    $("ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu li:odd").css(
        'background', '#black'
    );
});
```

It should be the same like this in css. I'm not using this one because not all browsers supports it. That's why im using jquery but it doesnt work...

```
ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu li:nth-child(even) {background: white;}
ul.typeahead.dropdown-menu li:nth-child(odd) {background: black;}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: script would only work if it was used in a callback for typeahaed since the html of the list is dynamically generated and therefore doesn't exist when you run your code

Comment: So... how do I fix this?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430183/how-to-check-if-number-of-elements-within-parent-is-even