# JQuery: How to find out how many children an element has?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, find, children

How can I use jQuery to find out how many children an element has?

Say I have the following structure:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="column1">
      <div id="asset1"></div>
      <div id="asset2"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="column2">
      <div id="asset1"></div>
      <div id="asset2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to find out how many children the div element: container, has. In this case it would return 2...

Comment: Here this the question, too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children

Comment: @antonio Moore This was my question too, thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
$("#container").children().length
```

Comment: i was just behind 7 seconds XD

Comment: Speed typing challenge? Nooooo not at all

Comment: +1 Yours makes more sense but I'll leave mine as an alternative.

Comment: Wouldnt `size()` be used instead of length when counting dom elements?

Comment: @Johan `length` saves you from an additional function call

Comment: @Johan: No, `size` just returns `length`; see the [`size` docs](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

Comment: *"however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call."* - [the docs also mentioned](http://api.jquery.com/size/)

Comment: @Joseph: Sorry, my comment above was for Johan, not for you. I typed `@jo` and pressed tab, and missed that it got the wrong name. :-) Just got it in time to be able to edit it.

Comment: @Johan: Me too. The code for `size` literally is `return this.length;`, and has been since jQuery v1.0. I see no point to it at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you. is it possible for all browsers

Comment: if I have a same class elements and what to know how many they are, are there any other fast way to do?

Comment: @Kermani: I'm afraid I don't understand that question, but it doesn't sound like it relates to this answer, so I'd suggest posting an actual question (with your HTML, and the code you're unsure of).

Answer (score 8):

Use the direct children selector (>) and the length property:

```
$('#container > *').length
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/TtV8d/