# What prevents .row div from scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to scroll each row horizontally. So on right arrow keypress normally the whole row should scroll to the left. In fact it was scrolling, before I added `display: table` in order to get the real width of row.

How to scroll .row?

Example, to show problem(need resize client area to show 2 cells):
https://jsfiddle.net/souren/98rddfzp/8/

Comment: Do I understand right, that with `display: table` or `inline-block` div will never feel that it's necessary to scroll? If yes, then how else I can get the real width of .row, after adding cells into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `display: table`, try using `box-sizing: border-box`.

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and [this](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

Here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98rddfzp/11/).

Comment: But then I am not able to get the real space, occupied by cells inside of .row. `$("#row" + currentRowIndex).width()` always returns the size of the window and not the size of row, including invisible area.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what size you want to get. The size of all de `.row` including the cells in it? As in your example, all the cells have the same size.

Comment: Each time I append a new cell into `.row` the size of `.row` is presumably growing. With one cell 210, two cells 420 etc.. I would like to get the overall size with current cells. But it looks like I'm somehow on wrong track. The reason behind all this is that I want to be able to scroll until very last cell, so the last cell will be under red div. For that I wanted to extend the width of `.row` as it approaches to the end. But extension will not work, because in fact I am not extended overall area occupied by all cells, but only area limitied by size of the window. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Well, you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children) to count the number of children each row has, and based on your cell index, check if you're in the penultimate cell, in which in that case, you could make the red square move one cell. Hope this helps in any way.

Comment: I would really like not to move the red selection div, but scroll the very last cell under the red selection div. One solution I tried is add fake cells to the end, but then decided to see if I can resize the row to have same effect without fake cells.

Comment: Well, you could add a hidden cell at the very end, but that would create a space in your page. I'm not sure about resizing your row, sincerely i haven't fully checked how your jquery works to scroll the rows.