# JQuery-find-each in Chrome: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I created a demo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bigdata.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(result){

        var count = 0;
        var bigdata = $(result).find("root");
        bigdata.find("row").each(function(index, element) {
            count++;
        });
        console.log('(125148 is good, 125149 is not good; count =', count);
    }
});
```

with the following `bigdata.xml`:

```
<root>
    <row/>
    <row/>
    .
    .
    .
    <row/>
</root>
```

where the number of `<row/>` causes the issue. If I have 125148 `<row/>` then it's fine. However if I have 125149 `<row/>` then I have this error in browsers with Chrome engine:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

In Firefox I don't have this error even if the number of `<row/>` is much higher. What's the problem here? Is it Chrome issue? Or JQuery?

In my application I have to display more than 130 thousand items, so I have to resolve this issue somehow.

EDIT:
Number 125149 is the limit on Windows10. Now I tried under Linux and Chrome can handle 125235 rows there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you dont need to loop over the row as you are just trying to get the count?

[How can I count the number of children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546659/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-children)

Try counting it this way

Comment: in the application each `row` contains attributes that I have to process, the demo was created to demostrate the issue on minimum code